# How to use #'package-name with 'in-package?

Tags: package, common-lisp

I'm trying to write a simple function that will create the package and go to the package created. To do so, I'm trying the following:

```
(let ((my-pack (make-package "dada")))
   (in-package (package-name my-pack)))
```

However, it's not working. Under closer look, I noticed that it's because in-package is macro - and it accepts either symbol, or string as the name. I can't try any funny tricks like defining variable holding the name beforehand, because name of symbol holding the name will be interpreted as name of package I'm looking for.

So, how can I

I'm using SBCL 1.1.18 on Linux, but I would like the solution to be cross-platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing really like 'going to a package'. You can tell Lisp, which is the *current package* is. This then affects further lookup/creation of symbols (for example during *reading*) and printing of symbols.

One thing you can do is:

```
CL-USER 53 > (cl:setf cl:*package* (cl:make-package "DADA"))
#<The DADA package, 0/16 internal, 0/16 external>
```

Above creates the package named `DADA` and sets `cl:*package*` to it.

```
DADA 54 > 'foo
FOO

DADA 55 > (cl:describe 'foo)

FOO is a SYMBOL
NAME          "FOO"
VALUE         #<unbound value>
FUNCTION      #<unbound function>
PLIST         NIL
PACKAGE       #<The DADA package, 1/16 internal, 0/16 external>
```

Set the default package back to `CL-USER`:

```
COMMON-LISP 57 > (cl:setf *package* (cl:find-package "CL-USER"))
#<The COMMON-LISP-USER package, 1307/4096 internal, 0/4 external>
```

`in-package` exists to also tell Lisp to change the *current package* during *compile time*.

Comment: "Going to a package" was a mental shortcut :)